# Loading Map from Text File Java

Tags: java, dictionary, tile

I'm makeing a 2d game and im stuck at map. I want it to be stored in text file like this

```
[block name] [x] [y]
wall 20 20

wall 20 40

wall 20 60

wall 20 80

wall 20 100

wall 20 120

wall 20 140

wall 20 160

wall 20 180

wall 20 200
```

I have a code that reads that

```
       public void TileLayer() throws IOException{
       InputStream inp = (InputStream) getClass().getResourceAsStream("/image/msdf.txt");
    BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inp));
    String str;
    while ((str = in.readLine()) != null) {
           if (str.startsWith("wall ")) {
         float x = Float.valueOf(str.split(" ")[1]);
         float y = Float.valueOf(str.split(" ")[2]);

           }
    }

   }
```

but than how to display it? How to buffer it ?

Thanks for help.
If you have any questions youst ask and i'll answer.

Full code

```
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Image;
import java.awt.Toolkit;
import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;
import java.awt.event.KeyListener;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;

import javax.swing.Timer;
import javax.imageio.ImageIO;
import javax.swing.JFrame;

import org.omg.CORBA.portable.InputStream;

import java.io.Reader;

public class NewTest extends JFrame implements KeyListener {
/**
 * 
 */
private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
private Image TestImage;
private BufferedImage bf;
private int cordX = 100;
private int cordY = 100;
private boolean down, up, left, right;

public NewTest() throws IOException {
    setTitle("Testing....");
    setSize(200, 200);
    imageLoader();
    setVisible(true);
}



public void imageLoader() throws IOException {
    TestImage = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getImage("image/Koala.jpg");

    addKeyListener(this);
}

public void update(Graphics g){
       paint(g);
}

public void paint(Graphics g){

    bf = new BufferedImage( this.getWidth(),this.getHeight(), BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_RGB);

try{
animation(bf.getGraphics());
g.drawImage(bf,0,0,null);
}catch(Exception ex){

}
}

public void animation(Graphics g) {
    super.paint(g);
    g.drawImage(TestImage, cordX, cordY,20 , 20, this);

   }
   public void TileLayer() throws IOException{
       InputStream inp = (InputStream) getClass().getResourceAsStream("/image/msdf.txt");
    BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inp));
    String str;
    while ((str = in.readLine()) != null) {
           if (str.startsWith("wall ")) {
         float x = Float.valueOf(str.split(" ")[1]);
         float y = Float.valueOf(str.split(" ")[2]);

           }
    }

   }


public static void main(String[] args) {
    try {
        new NewTest();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

public void keyPressed(KeyEvent ke) {
    switch (ke.getKeyCode()) {
        case KeyEvent.VK_RIGHT:
            right = true;
            break;
        case KeyEvent.VK_LEFT:
            left = true;
            break;
        case KeyEvent.VK_DOWN:
            down = true;
            break;
        case KeyEvent.VK_UP:
            up = true;
            break;
    }
    updateState();
}

public void keyReleased(KeyEvent ke) {
    switch (ke.getKeyCode()) {
        case KeyEvent.VK_RIGHT:
            right = false;
            break;
        case KeyEvent.VK_LEFT:
            left = false;
            break;
        case KeyEvent.VK_DOWN:
            down = false;
            break;
        case KeyEvent.VK_UP:
            up = false;
            break;
    }
    updateState();
}

protected void updateState() {
    if (right) {
        cordX += 5;
    } else if (left) {
        cordX -= 5;

    }
    if (down) {
        cordY += 5;
    } else if (up) {
        cordY -= 3;
    }
    if (down && up) {
        cordY += 0;
        cordX += 0;
    }
    if (right && left) {
        cordX += 0;
        cordY += 0;
    }

    System.out.printf("X:");System.out.println(cordX);
    System.out.printf("Y:");System.out.println(cordY);
    repaint();
}

public void keyTyped(KeyEvent ke) {
}
```

}

Comment: It's not clear what you're asking to do with those values now that you have them, what part of using them isn't clear to you.

Comment: Now i have values but how to make them blocks